# How to create chart with multiple series in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, bar-chart, oracle-apex

I have a bar chart that it works fine, but the chart use just one series for all bars and all bars have same color. What should I do for creating different series for each records of my query?
This is my query:

```
select customeTable.firstname||' '||customeTable.lastname as fullName, customeTable.sumHour as sumHour
from (
    select sum(projActivity.ACTIVITY_HOUR) as sumHour, users.FIRST_NAME as firstname, users.LAST_NAME as lastname
        from SITA_PROJECT_TASKS_ACTIVITY projActivity
    inner join SITA_PROJECT_TASKS projTask on projTask.ID=projActivity.TASK_ID and projTask.PROJECT_ID=:P39_PROJECT_ID
    inner join SITA_USERS users on users.ID=projActivity.CREATOR_ID
    where
        (:P39_FROM_DATE is null or projActivity.ACTIVITY_DATE>=:P39_FROM_DATE) 
    and (:P39_TO_DATE is null or projActivity.ACTIVITY_DATE<=:P39_TO_DATE)
    group by users.FIRST_NAME,users.LAST_NAME
) customeTable
```

Comment: What distinguishes your series?  What would you add to the query for the series?

Comment: Series are created based on fullName

Answer (score 1):

If you have a column in your query that can be used to derive the name of the series, you can set that column as the name of the series. Demo application can be seen [here](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/adptest/r/ej-testing/multiple-series-demo).

[image: apex developer screenshot]

[image: chart screenshot]

Comment: This is static select. I have just one select as you see in my question. I don't know how many column I have.

Comment: How is it that you want to break your data up into Series? You need to add some logic to your select to determine what series they belong in or use an existing column like **full_name** to use that as the series.

Comment: I use full_name column but all bars have same color, I'm gonna edit my post and add picture of chart that you can see it

Comment: I wanted to take a picture and upload here, but I saw everything works fine!!!!! I don't know how and why but everything has been fixed!!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You'd do exactly what you said: *add another series*. How? Right-click the chart region name and select "Create series":

[image]

Every series can have its own query, or they can share the region's source - it depends on you. Fill other required properties and you should have several series on the same chart.

Comment: I don't know how many series I have. Because series are created dynamically, so how many series should I create?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure you can do that dynamically (i.e. create only one series which would cover all possible cases). So, how many? "Enough", I guess (if that helps, but I'm not sure of it).